# for the value of k in KNN

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I know that normally, if k = 1, then the object is simply assigned to the class of that single nearest neighbor. But I found a question which said that a point can be its own neighbor, and it ask me to find a k to minimize the training error. So I want to know in this case, can k be 1?

Comment: You have to be very careful when evaluating the "training set" using k-NN.

Answer (score 0):

When evaluating the training error using *k*-NN, you are classifying each instance in the training set using the training set itself.

If a point can be its own neighbor, then using `k = 1` will yield perfect performance as it will always predict the point's own label for each point. So, yes, using `k = 1` will certainly minimize the training error.